# Add multiple GCP HA instance to Unmanaged Instance Group by Terraform

Tags: git, google-cloud-platform, terraform, cloud, terraform-provider-gcp

I need to add multiple cross zonal GCP instances to UIG. But, below code is attaching only few instances to UIG.

It is working as expected (creating UIG and attaching instances to terraform created UIG) if **var.num_instances** count is greater than or equal to **length(data.google_compute_zones.available.names)**.

But , It does not attach instance in case **length(data.google_compute_zones.available.names)** is less than **var.num_instances**.

**main.tf**

```
data "google_compute_zones" "available" {
  project = var.project
  region  = var.region
}

module "google_uig" {
  source = "C:/Users/xxxx/OneDrive/Desktop/New folder/terraform-google-core/modules/compute_engine_uig"
  depends_on = [
    module.google_vm
  ]
  project = var.project
  # count   = var.num_instances
  count   = length(data.google_compute_zones.available.names) < var.num_instances ? length(data.google_compute_zones.available.names) : var.num_instances
  zone    = var.zone == null ? data.google_compute_zones.available.names[count.index % length(data.google_compute_zones.available.names)] : var.zone
  name         = "use1${[for zone in (data.google_compute_zones.available.names): substr(zone,-1,-1)][count.index]}-oss94-mta99-app-ig01"
  instances = element((module.google_vm[*].google_instance_id), count.index)
}
```

**terraform.tfvars**

```
project            = "gcp-test01"
region             = "us-central1"
num_instances      = "6"
image_project      = "gcp-kcfn01"
image_name         = "centos7-kent-v20220105"
instance_name      = "kcfn01-cfn01-apoc01-app"
tags               = ["oss01-mta-app", "usc1-sss-oss-snet01-local"]
machine_type       = "n1-standard-4"
disk_size          = "50"
disk_type          = "pd-standard"
boot_disk_size     = "50"
boot_disk_type     = "pd-standard"
network            = "cfn01-sss-net"
subnetwork         = "cfn01-usc1-sss-oss-snet01"
subnetwork_project = "gcp-kcfn01"
```

Comment: So you want to add six instances? But it doesn't do that if the region has less zones?

Comment: It is provisioning 6 instances in different zones. Like, 2 instances in zone A, 2 instances in zone B and rest instances in other zones C and D. But issue is coming to attchh all instances in UIG.

Comment: @MarkoE ,Can you help me here ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with how the zones work in GCP unfortunately so that makes it hard to understand the math.

Comment: Can someone please have a look on it ?